# C++11 on Code::Blocks in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, c++11, gcc

So I'm trying to run a simple hello world program with a thread. It's the standard hello world program that is used to introduce you to threads. I'm using Code::Blocks IDE on Ubuntu 14.04, I have gcc 4.8.2. I use the GCC compiler to build my project and I also checked the option `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]' but when I build the project I get this error:

```
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted`
```

I've seen solution which tell me to add `-pthread` and `-lthread` somewhere but I don't know where to write this... any help?

Comment: I don't know about Code::Blocks specifically, but usually there's somewhere in the project settings where you can add arbitrary compiler and linker flags. Optionally there might be a checkbox you can tick for this specific toggle.

Comment: I know, I've added `-pthread` and `-lthread` and it still doesn't work. I also tried adding `-lthread` in the linker options but I still get the same problem.

Comment: @captain: You stopped short of adding `-pthread` to the linker options, which is the fix :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "-pthread" to your linker options ("Linker settings" → "Other linker options").

- [source](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17290.0) (first Google result for `code blocks pthread`)

Comment: Thanks,man. I was adding `-pthread` in the compiler options. What about `-lpthread`? Do I need it?

Comment: @captain: try it and see (doubtful)